# django-ajax json response

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery

I have a django url : '127.0.0.1:8000/showsym' mapped to view returning json response

```
def get_symptoms(request):
    bp=BodySubPart.objects.get(body_subpart="head")
    data1=bp.symptoms.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', data1)
    return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/json')
```

now i am trying to parse this in ajx_form.html and code for that is :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hist</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
$.get('127.0.0.1:8000/showsym/', function(data1) {
       alert(data1);
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but it is not giving me any output
the page is coming blank

please help me here somebody

Answer (score 1):

It is because your code tries to get the url: /127.0.0.1:8000/showsym/

Change `127.0.0.1:8000/showsym/` to `/showsym/`.

I suggest you use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and name urls, assuming the [url name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) of /showsym is showsym:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('{% url showsym %}', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
    })
})
```